# Detect a change in any of four specific ranges, and perform one of two actions if that range is altered

Tags: excel, vba

I want to trigger data validation and a formatting macro on pasted data. This would identify when a change is made to any one of four specific ranges, and, if so, run one of two further macros.

I had a working version of this Sub. I tried to tidy it up so that only one set of msgbox would be deployed if an error was found, rather than one set per data validation breach. The code now doesn't trigger on data validation errors.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim aCell As Range
    Dim bCell As Range
    Dim cCell As Range
    Dim dCell As Range
    Dim Counter1 As Integer
    Dim Counter2 As Integer
    Dim Counter3 As Integer
    Dim Counter4 As Integer
    
    If Not Intersect(Target, Target.Worksheet.Range("B4:M6")) Is Nothing Then
    
        Sheets("Cell Count Sheet").Select
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect "ABC123"
    
        Call Cell_Count_Formatting
        
        Call Cell_Count_Average_Check
        
        Counter1 = 0
        
        For Each aCell In Range("B4:M6")
            If Not aCell.Validation.Value = True Then Counter1 = Counter1 + 1
        Next aCell
            
        If Counter1 > 0 Then
        
            Sheets("Cell Count Sheet").CircleInvalid
                
            MsgBox "At least one of the pasted values does not comply with the data validation rules for these cells", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "Data Validation Error with pasted data" & "1 of 2"
            MsgBox "Please check the cell count is pasted in cell B4." & vbNewLine & "Non-compliant data will be circled, please check all circled data", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Data Validation Error with pasted data" + "2 of 2"
            Sheets("Cell Count Sheet").CircleInvalid
        Else
        
            Sheets("Cell Count Sheet").Select
            ActiveSheet.Protect "ABC123"
        
        End If
    
    ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Target.Worksheet.Range("B9:M11")) Is Nothing Then
    
        Sheets("Cell Count Sheet").Select
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect "ABC123"
    
        Call Cell_Count_Formatting
        
        Call Cell_Count_Average_Check
        
        Counter2 = 0
        
        For Each bCell In Range("B4:M6")
            If Not bCell.Validation.Value = True Then Counter2 = Counter2 + 1
        Next bCell
            
        If Counter2 > 0 Then
        
            Sheets("Cell Count Sheet").CircleInvalid
                
            MsgBox "At least one of the pasted values does not comply with the data validation rules for these cells", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "Data Validation Error with pasted data" & "1 of 2"
            MsgBox "Please check the cell count is pasted in cell B4." & vbNewLine & "Non-compliant data will be circled, please check all circled data", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Data Validation Error with pasted data" + "2 of 2"
            Sheets("Cell Count Sheet").CircleInvalid
        Else
        
            Sheets("Cell Count Sheet").Select
            ActiveSheet.Protect "ABC123"
        
        End If

    ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Target.Worksheet.Range("B48:M50")) Is Nothing Then
        If Range("B48").Value = 1 Then
    
            Sheets("Cell Count Sheet").Select
            ActiveSheet.Unprotect "ABC123"
        
            Call Cell_Count_Formatting
            
            Call Cell_Count_Average_Check
            
            Counter3 = 0
            
            For Each cCell In Range("B4:M6")
                If Not cCell.Validation.Value = True Then Counter3 = Counter3 + 1
            Next cCell
                
            If Counter3 > 0 Then
            
                Sheets("Cell Count Sheet").CircleInvalid
                    
                MsgBox "At least one of the pasted values does not comply with the data validation rules for these cells", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "Data Validation Error with pasted data" & "1 of 2"
                MsgBox "Please check the cell count is pasted in cell B4." & vbNewLine & "Non-compliant data will be circled, please check all circled data", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Data Validation Error with pasted data" + "2 of 2"
                Sheets("Cell Count Sheet").CircleInvalid
            Else
            
                Sheets("Cell Count Sheet").Select
                ActiveSheet.Protect "ABC123"
            
            End If
        End If
        
    ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Target.Worksheet.Range("B48:M50")) Is Nothing Then
        If Range("B48").Value = 1 Then
    
            Sheets("Cell Count Sheet").Select
            ActiveSheet.Unprotect "ABC123"
        
            Call Cell_Count_Formatting
            
            Call Cell_Count_Average_Check
            
            Counter4 = 0
            
            For Each dCell In Range("B4:M6")
                If Not dCell.Validation.Value = True Then Counter4 = Counter4 + 1
            Next dCell
                
            If Counter4 > 0 Then
            
                Sheets("Cell Count Sheet").CircleInvalid
                    
                MsgBox "At least one of the pasted values does not comply with the data validation rules for these cells", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "Data Validation Error with pasted data" & "1 of 2"
                MsgBox "Please check the cell count is pasted in cell B4." & vbNewLine & "Non-compliant data will be circled, please check all circled data", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Data Validation Error with pasted data" + "2 of 2"
                Sheets("Cell Count Sheet").CircleInvalid
            Else
            
                Sheets("Cell Count Sheet").Select
                ActiveSheet.Protect "ABC123"
            
            End If
        End If
    
    Else
    End If
    
End Sub
```

I tried a "Counter" in the above code to collate the number of times data validation isn't met and then output an error if this is >0. This doesn't work.

Comment: You're checking B48:M50 twice?  Do you really only want to know if there's an issue in B4:M6?

Comment: If you just need to check a number of different ranges you can do this: `If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("B4:M6,B9:M11,B48:M50")) Is Nothing Then`

Answer (score 0):

The code trigger on changes but the: For Each cCell In Range("B4:M6")  refers the cells in the "Cell Count Sheet" because you Select it.

Your code can be smaller like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   Dim aCell As Range, Counter As Integer, ws As Worksheet, rng As Range
   'in next line check three ranges, you can add more...
   If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("B4:M6,B9:M11,B48:M50")) Is Nothing Then  '@Tim Williams comment
   'If Not Intersect(Target, Union(Me.Range("B4:M6"), Me.Range("B9:M11"), Me.Range("B48:M50"))) Is Nothing Then
      Set ws = Worksheets("Cell Count Sheet")
      
      'here you don't need the "ws.Select" line, but maybe your code in Cell_Count_Formatting or Cell_Count_Average_Check
      'need the Worksheets("Cell Count Sheet") to be the Active sheet
      
      'try not to use .Select to refer an object but mention it explicitly. Like the ws.Unprotect "..."
      ws.Select
      ws.Unprotect "ABC123"
      '
      Call Cell_Count_Formatting
      Call Cell_Count_Average_Check
      Counter = 0
      For Each aCell In Me.Range("B4:M6")
          If Not aCell.Validation.value = True Then Counter = Counter + 1
      Next aCell
      Me.Select
      If Counter > 0 Then
         ws.CircleInvalid
         MsgBox "At least one of the pasted values does not comply with the data validation rules for these cells", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "Data Validation Error with pasted data" & "1 of 2"
                 MsgBox "Please check the cell count is pasted in cell B4." & vbNewLine & "Non-compliant data will be circled, please check all circled data", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Data Validation Error with pasted data" + "2 of 2"
                 Sheets("Cell Count Sheet").CircleInvalid
      Else
         ws.Protect "ABC123"
      End If
      
   End If
End Sub
```